# Why won't my program output i?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

My program is supposed to find the factorial of a number by creating a function, and display the results in a table format. In the main body of my program I have a `cout` for `i`, and my function `factNum i`, but only `factNum i` is being output? How do I make it so that both `i` and `factNum i` are displayed next to each other? And also, how do I fix my for loop so that it will continue to ask the user for numbers after the first run through?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;


int factNum ( int num)
{
  int answer = 1;

  for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
  {
      answer = answer * i;
  }
  return answer;
}

int main()
{
  int num;

  cout << " Enter a number, or -1 to quit: " << endl;
  cin>> num;

  for (int i= 1; i<=num; i++){
    cout<< i << factNum(i)<< endl;
  }

  if( num == -1)
    cout<< " Goodbye! "<< endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your program _does_ output both `i` and `i!`. Look closely.

Comment: I guarantee that the value of `i` is output right before `factNum(i)`, look harder.  You don't add a space or anything to separate them.

Answer (score 4):

> In the main body of my program I have a cout for i, and my function
>   factNum i, but only factNum i is being output? How do I make it so
>   that both i and factNum i are displayed next to each other?

Your program does in fact output both `i` and `i!` right next to each other:

```
cout << i << factNum(i) << endl;
```

There's just no space between the numbers, so what you're seeing is this:

```
11
22
36
424
...
```

If you inserted a space between the two numbers:

```
cout << i << " " << factNum(i) << endl;
```

you would get this instead:

```
1 1
2 2
3 6
4 24
...
```

---

> And also, how do I fix my for loop so that it will continue to ask the
>   user for numbers after the first run through?

You can refactor the code in `main()` into another function and simply call that again after asking the user for more numbers. That I leave as an exercise to you. If you still struggle with that, you can post another question (but only after you've really tried it out yourself).

Comment: that was incredibly useful, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

> only factNum i is being output

Are you sure about that?  Have you looked at the actual numbers being output?  Try adding a space.

Comment: thanks for the tip! Can you help me out with the for loop issue?

Comment: @MikeShamus: If you have 2 separate questions, then you should make 2 separate posts.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
int main()
{

int num;
while(1)
{
cout << " Enter a number, or -1 to quit: " << endl;
cin>> num;


for (int i= 1; i<=num; i++)
{
cout<< i << "   "<<factNum(i)<< endl;
}

if( num == -1)
cout<< " Goodbye! "<< endl;
}
return 0; }
```